# Flow / flowtype - how to extend a declared module

Tags: flowtype

In a `React Native` app I am assigning a custom method to the `console` e.g. `console.foo = () => {}`. The console module type is already [defined here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/flow/console.js). So I get the error: `Property not found in object type`. How can I extend & declare a `console` module with a custom method type?

Comment: Why stick it on `console` when you could make it a custom module? Then you can just `import foo from './console-foo';` and things are infinitely easier to follow and typecheck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, Flow does not support extending/overriding flow/lib types:

https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/396